# Rails | Link Sharing App | Database Modelling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am trying to learn Rails by building a link sharing app.

1) User can submit a Post along with a reference to other users who have created that post.

2) So, a post belongs to a user(who submitted it) and also other users (who created the post)

Currently, I have 2 tables

1) Users
   2) Posts

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :submitted_user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
 #belongs to multiple other users who have created the post#
end
```

Should I use `has_many through` and create a join table `PostCreators` that has a user_id and post_id. In that case `Can I write multiple has_many :posts?`

```
class User
 has_many :posts #submitted_user in post
 has_many :posts, through: :post_creators 
end

class Post 
  belongs_to :submitted_user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
  has_many :creators, through: :post_creators
end

class PostCreator
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Comment: @Mehendhar        Post can be created by many users ?

Comment: @Vishal Take the example of ProductHunt, a post has one hunter and multiple makers. I want to do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_posts
  has_many :posts, through: :user_posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :submitted_user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'submitted_user_id'
  has_many :user_posts
  has_many :posts, through: :user_posts
end

class UserPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Also write a migration to add submitted_user_id to Post table

```
p = Post.last
```

`p.users` => will return array of created users

`p.submitted_user` => will return submitter user object

Comment: Thank you @Dias, but a post can have multiple creators.

Comment: Mehendhar, I have updated the answer , use through model relationship or just has_and_belongs_to_many as @SergioTulentsev commented

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to create Post and User Join table and add association has_many through to store additional data on join table.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_posts
  has_many :posts, through: :user_posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_posts
  has_many :users, through: :user_posts
end

class UserPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
  enum status: { submitter: 0, creators: 1 }
end
```

So, if I want to find out the creators of a post, I do

```
post = Post.first
UserPost.where(post: post).creators
```

By default, when a user submits a post, UserPost record of that user and post will be created with a enum status of 0.

When the submitter selects the post's creators, UserPost records will be created with that post, selected users and enum status of 1

I am not sure if this is the best way. Please comment if you think of an optimal way of doing this.